# Como agregar una discriminación en un select

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente query que funciona bien, que trae el resultado de de una tabla que muestra X numero de veces los canales del campo "Canal" (canal1 , canal2).

Cuando X = tipo de empleado (trabajador, jefe , directivo).

Es decir cada canal tendria 3 resultados en mi tabla. Ej:

```
Canal1, trabajador
Canal1, jefe
Canal1, directivo
Canal2, trabajador
Canal2, jefe
Canal2, directivo
```

PERO! si el campo `Jefe` no existe en `Canal2` este no aparezca

```
Canal1, trabajador
Canal1, jefe
Canal1, directivo
Canal2, trabajador
Canal2, directivo
```

Y en la tercera/cuarta columna muestra la suma/resta de cuanto personal tiene activo/vacante.

Pero quiero agregar que NO muestre a los directivos en este ejemplo:

O si existe un camino mas fácil para no mostrar el resultado de directivo

```
    $sql123 = "
    with total as(
      select us.canal, us.puesto, count(*) as [Rutas]
      from usuario us
      where us.us_nombre_real NOT LIKE '%VACANTE%' and us.dni != 'P0'
      group by us.canal, us.puesto),
    smartphone as (
      select us.canal, us.puesto, count(*) as [Smartphone]
      from usuario us
      where us.cuenta_smart LIKE '%Si%' and us.dni != 'P0'
      group by us.canal, us.puesto),
    laptop as (
      select us.canal, us.puesto, count(*) as [Laptops]
      from usuario us
      where us.Laptop LIKE '%Si%' and us.us_nombre_real NOT LIKE '%VACANTE%' and us.dni != 'P0'
      group by us.canal, us.puesto),

    pruebaRutas   as (SELECT count(*) as [Rutas]   FROM usuario us WHERE us.dni = 'P0'),
    pruebaEquipos as (SELECT count(*) as [Equipos] FROM usuario us WHERE us.dni = 'P0' and us.cuenta_smart LIKE '%Si%'),
    pruebaLaptops as (SELECT count(*) as [Laptops] FROM usuario us WHERE us.dni = 'P0' and us.Laptop LIKE '%Si%'),

    vacantes as (
      select us.canal, us.puesto, count(*) as [Vacantes]
      from usuario us
      where us.us_nombre_real LIKE '%VACANTE%' and us.dni != 'P0'
      group by us.canal, us.puesto),
    autorizados as (
      select us.canal, us.puesto, count(*) as [Autorizados]
      from usuario us
      WHERE us.dni != 'P0'
      group by us.canal, us.puesto)

        select cn.[descripcion] as [canal], pt.[descripcion] as [Puesto],
        tt.[Rutas] as [Activos], --tt.[Rutas]
    CASE WHEN vc.[Vacantes] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE vc.[Vacantes] END as [Vacantes],
    CASE WHEN au.[Autorizados] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE au.[Autorizados] END as [Autorizados],
     --tt.[Rutas]
    CASE WHEN sm.smartphone IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE
    sm.smartphone
    END as [Smartphone],
    CASE WHEN lp.Laptops IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE
    lp.Laptops
    END as [Laptops]
    from total tt
    left join canal cn on cn.id = tt.canal
    left join puesto pt on pt.id = tt.puesto
    left join smartphone sm on sm.canal = tt.canal and sm.puesto = tt.puesto
    left join vacantes vc on vc.canal = tt.canal and vc.puesto = tt.puesto
    left join laptop lp on lp.canal = tt.canal and lp.puesto = tt.puesto
    left join autorizados au on au.canal = tt.canal and au.puesto = tt.puesto
    UNION SELECT 'Prueba' as [canal], 'Prueba' as [Puesto], 0 as [Activos], 0 as [Vacantes], 0 as [Autorizados], (SELECT * FROM pruebaEquipos) as [Equipos], (SELECT * FROM pruebaLaptops) as [Laptops]
    order by cn.descripcion asc, pt.descripcion asc
";
```

Esta es mi tabla :

```
<table class="table table-responsive jambo_table table-striped table-bordered bulk_action">
  <!--- id="datatable" --->
<thead>  
    <tr class="fit">
        <th class="fit col-md-1" >Canal</th>
        <th valign="middle" class="fit col-md-1">Puesto</th>
        <th valign="middle" class="fit col-md-1">Autorizados</th>
        <th valign="middle" class="fit col-md-1">Activos</th>
        <th valign="middle" class="fit col-md-1">Vacantes</th>

        <th valign="middle" class="fit col-md-1">Smarthphone</th>
        <th valign="middle" class="fit col-md-1">Laptops</th>
    </tr>
</thead>    
<?php
    $result123 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql123);
    $total = array('Activos' => 0,'Vacantes' => 0, 'Autorizados' => 0, 'Smartphone' => 0, 'Laptops' => 0); 
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result123)) {
$canal_1=$row['canal'];
$Puesto_1=$row['Puesto'];
$autorizado_1=$row['Autorizados'];
$Activos_1=$row['Activos'];
$Vacantes_1=$row['Vacantes'];
$Smartphone_1=$row['Smartphone'];
$Lapdops_1=$row['Laptops'];
        ?>
      </tbody>  
        <tr>tercero
            <td valign="middle"><?php echo $canal_1; ?></td>
            <td valign="middle"><?php echo $Puesto_1; ?></td>
            <td valign="middle"><?php echo $autorizado_1; $total['Autorizados'] += $row['Autorizados']?></td>
            <td valign="middle"><?php echo $Activos_1; $total['Activos'] += $row['Activos']?></td>
            <td valign="middle"><?php echo $Vacantes_1; $total['Vacantes'] += $row['Vacantes']?></td>

            <td valign="middle"><?php echo $Smartphone_1; $total['Smartphone'] += $row['Smartphone']?></td>
            <td valign="middle"><?php echo $Lapdops_1; $total['Laptops'] += $row['Laptops']?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td valign="middle"><b>Total</b></td>
        <td valign="middle"><b><?php echo $total['Autorizados'] ?></b></td>
        <td valign="middle"><b><?php echo $total['Activos'] ?></b></td>
        <td valign="middle"><b><?php echo $total['Vacantes'] ?></b></td>

        <td valign="middle"><b><?php echo $total['Smartphone'] ?></b></td>
        <td valign="middle"><b><?php echo $total['Laptops'] ?></b></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: porque no usas el IS NOT NULL, para que no retorne en tu consulta sql los campos nulls...

Comment: Hola Tegito23, el problema es que quiero que no se vea el campo Jefe , ya que los valores null no se muestran

Comment: por ello, con IS NOT NULL traes los campos que no son nulls

Comment: ejemplo SELECT nombre, apellido, cargo.nombre as cargo FROM personal LEFT JOIN cargo ON persona.id_cargo = cargo.id WHERE cargo.id IS NOT NULL

Comment: en este caso retorna los registros cuyo cargo no sea null

Comment: Disculpa creo que no entendi muy bien tu comentario, ya que nome queda claro como ignora el todos los valores que contenga nombre "directivo" , en este caso lo e "medio" solucionado discriminando la tabla en iner join de usuario para puesto relacionando primero la "id" que empalma mi primer resultado con el nuevo renombrandolo a Puesto y no puesto en la misma consulta y en sulugar un us.puesto !='8' as us.suario !='8' en ambas consultas